# Make authenticated API requests from Apollo studio explorer to Apollo express server that is protected by a third party auth service (keycloak)

Tags: express, cookies, graphql, keycloak, apollo-server

I am using keycloak to authenticate my Apollo server express API. Including the bearer token in the Apollo studio header is not enough to authenticate the studio as the request needs to contain certain cookies provided by keycloak that are set in the browser when I log into the front end app.

The front end sends this cookie along with the bearer token to the server. While I have the option to manually define an authentication token in Apollo studio, I don’t know of a way to attach the cookie to the request.

Interestingly enough, when I use postman to query my API, postman will actually extract the cookie in the browser that has already been set by logging into the front end and include it in any postman requests to the URL that corresponds to the cookie, so I can make authenticated requests with postman if I have already logged into my front end. Unfortunately Apollo studio does not do this.

How can I provide Authentication with the cookie from my Apollo studio? It’s a bit tricky since Apollo studio is not hosted by my backend application. Can I have express middleware to insert the cookie in requests coming from Apollo studio? What would this look like?

I’ve also heard talk about creating a proxy but I don’t really understand this option, is this a viable solution and how would it work?